# Value to NaN when Support or Resistance Broken?

Tags: pine-script

I've been attempting to modify the following script to make it so when the s1 or r1 levels are broken their value goes to NaN. Removing fixnan didn't work. Any help is appreciated. Here is the code:

```
toggleBreaks = input(true, title='Show Breaks')
leftBars = input(15, title='Left Bars ')
rightBars = input(15, title='Right Bars')
volumeThresh = input(20, title='Volume Threshold')
//
highUsePivot = fixnan(ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)[1])
lowUsePivot = fixnan(ta.pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)[1])

r1 = plot(highUsePivot, color=change(highUsePivot) ? na : #FF0000,  linewidth=3, offset=-(rightBars+1), title="Resistance")
s1 = plot(lowUsePivot, color=change(lowUsePivot) ? na : #233dee,  linewidth=3, offset=-(rightBars+1), title="Support")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using vitruvius's answer as a starting point I was able to pinpoint a functional solution via the following code:

````
toggleBreaks = input(true, title='Show Breaks')
leftBars = input(15, title='Left Bars ')
rightBars = input(15, title='Right Bars')
volumeThresh = input(20, title='Volume Threshold')
//

highUsePivot = fixnan(ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)[1])
if ta.highest(high, 15) > highUsePivot
    highUsePivot := na
lowUsePivot = fixnan(ta.pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)[1])
if ta.lowest(low, 15) < lowUsePivot
    lowUsePivot := na


r1 = plot(highUsePivot, color=change(highUsePivot) ? na : #FF0000,  linewidth=3, offset=-(rightBars+1), title="Resistance")
s1 = plot(lowUsePivot, color=change(lowUsePivot) ? na : #233dee,  linewidth=3, offset=-(rightBars+1), title="Support")```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can heck if a support level is broken with `high >= your_support_level`. Then assign `na` to your variable once this condition is `true`.

Or you can check if the price is above the support level and then not show it.

```
show_high = (high < highUsePivot)
show_low = (low > lowUsePivot)

r1 = plot(show_high ? highUsePivot : na, color=show_high ? #FF0000 : na, offset=-(rightBars+1), title="Resistance", style=plot.style_circles)
s1 = plot(show_low ? lowUsePivot : na, color=show_low ? #233dee : na, offset=-(rightBars+1), title="Support", style=plot.style_circles)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping with this. I think you have the right idea, but I'm seeing some things after applying that code that don't make sense. For example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AMETOHZmeLH7WA2X4fb8dWoBzvzinUQC/view

Comment: After doing some bar replays I've found that those visual anomalies in my screenshot above can be deceiving. The only way to know for sure how the code is working is to watch it in real time or replay it.